# Pandas set column value based on other columns value with list item by iteration

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to set the value of a pandas column based on another columns value. The new value should be set by iterating through a list, that has the same length like the unique values of `col1`

Example:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,2,2,3,3,4], 'col2': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
items_to_add=[5,2,11,9]
#list has length of unique values in `column1`
```

Now i want to add for example 5 to `column2` if `column1`is 1 and 2 to all `column2` rows where `column1` is 2 ....
So i should get:

```
col1    col2
1       5
2       2
2       2
2       2
3       11
3       11
4       9
```

This code throws me an syntax error but i do not know why

```
items_to_add=[5,2,11,9]
for i in range(len(items_to_add)):
    df['col2'][df.col1[i]] = items_to_add[i]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can i fix it?

Comment: Don't you get any error in `df  = df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace the values in `col1` by creating a dictionary i.e

```
di =  dict(zip(df['col1'].unique(), items_to_add))
# {1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 11, 4: 9}
df['col3'] = df['col1'].map(di)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     5
1     2     1     2
2     2     1     2
3     2     1     2
4     3     1    11
5     3     1    11
6     4     1     9
```

Comment: do you know by any chance how to do it in case I want to group not only by `col1`but the case that there is another column and i want the unique combinations of them?  @Dark

Comment: @Mauritius I cant say anything without seeing the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you do

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: items_to_add[x-1])
```

By doing this you create a new column `col2` where for every `x` in `df[col1]`, you choose the `(x-1)th` indexed value of `items_to_add`.

Comment: that looks good but it tells me. `list indices must be integer not float` ... no idea why he thinks z is float

Comment: Ohhhh you would have to make sure that `df['col1']` is of int type or cast the `x` to int like `items_to_add[int(x)-1]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove duplicates then map,

```
df['col1'].map(dict(zip(df['col1'].drop_duplicates(),items_to_add)))
#out[]
0     5
1     2
2     2
3     2
4    11
5    11
6     9
```

Comment: i want to keep the duplicates. otherwise that would be probably a good way to do it

Comment: check the output now